# html2canvas is not loading images inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, html2canvas

I have the following component on React with NextJs13:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

const StoryCard = ({ children, color }) => {
  // Para compartir como imagen
  const storyCardRef = useRef();
  const shareStoryCard = async () => {
    try {
      const canvas = await html2canvas(storyCardRef.current);
      const image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const blob = await (await fetch(image)).blob();

      if (navigator.share) {
        await navigator.share({
          files: [new File([blob], 'storycard.png', { type: 'image/png' })],
          title: 'Check out my favorite anime genres!',
        });
      } else {
        // Alternativa para navegadores que no soportan compartir archivos
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = image;
        link.download = 'storycard.png';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Error sharing the story card:', error);
    }
  };
  // Para guardar la imagen
  const saveStoryCard = async () => {
    try {
      const canvas = await html2canvas(storyCardRef.current);
      const image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      // Crear un enlace para la descarga
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = image;
      link.download = 'storycard.png'; // o podrías usar un nombre de archivo dinámico si lo prefieres
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Error saving the story card:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={storyCardRef} id="series-story" className={`story story--${color}-gradient`}>
        <div className="story__content">
          {children}
        </div>
        <div className="story__footer">
          <p className="story__footer-link">animanga-wrapped.vercel.app</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="story__button-container">
        <button type="button" onClick={shareStoryCard} className="story__button">Share</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={saveStoryCard} className="story__button">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

StoryCard.displayName = 'StoryCard';

export default StoryCard;
```

Some of the children props contain images hosted on Cloudinary. Everything is working well BUT the images. They are not included on the final image generated by html2canvas. Everything is OK: fonts, css styles, etc. But the image isn't there. Only the space.

Any ideas?